# Finding the amount of combination of three numbers in a sequence which fulfills a specific requirement

Tags: algorithm

The question is, given a number D and a sequence of numbers with amount N, find the amount of the combinations of three numbers that have a highest difference value within it that does not exceed the value D. For example:

```
D = 3, N = 4
Sequence of numbers: 1 2 3 4

Possible combinations: 1 2 3 (3-1 = 2 <= D), 1 2 4 (4 - 1 = 3 <= D), 1 3 4, 2 3 4.

Output: 4
```

What I've done: [link](https://gist.github.com/TakeNoteIAmHere/53c194744c9b10aafef9b1d917f564fd)

Well my concept is: iterate through the whole sequence of numbers and find the smallest number that exceeds the D value when subtracted to the current compared number. Then, find the combinations between those two numbers with the currently compared number being a fixed value (which means combination of n [numbers between the two numbers] taken 2). If even the biggest number in the sequence subtracted with the currently compared number does not exceed D, then use a combination of the whole elements taken 3.

N can be as big as 10^5 with the smallest being 1 and D can be as big as 10^9 with the smallest being 1 too.

Problem with my algorithm: overflow occurs when I do a combination of the 1st element and 10^5th element. How can I fix this? Is there a way to calculate that large amount of combination without actually doing the factorials?

**EDIT:**

Overflow occurs when worst case happens: currently compared number is still in index 0 while all other numbers, when subtracted with the currently compared number, is still smaller than D. For example, the value of number at index 0 is `1`, the value of number at index 10^5 is `10^5 + 1` and D is `10^9`. Then, my algorithm will attempt to calculate the factorial of `10^5 - 0` which then overflows. The factorial will be used to calculate the combination of 10^5 taken 3.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Linking to off-site code is not generally acceptable.

Comment: As you can see from the given answers, you also need to clarify your problem.

Comment: How do you get overflow?  You're subtracting two positive values that are within the integer range.

Comment: @Prune Hi, subtracting doesn't cause overflow. It's when I find the factorial of the subtraction of the two numbers (which can be as big as 10^5 - 1) does it overflow (I'm using the result for combination).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you seek for items in value range `D` in sorted list, and get index difference `M`, then you should calculate `C(M,3)`.

But for such combination number you don't need to use huge factorials:

```
 C(M,3) = M! / (6 * (M-3)!) = M * (M-1) * (M-2) / 6
```

To diminish intermediate results even more:

```
 A = (M - 1) * (M - 2) / 2
 A = (A * M) / 3
```

Comment: I see.... So that's where I got it wrong. So instead of calculating the factorial of the numerator and then divide it by the factorial of the denominator, we simplify the mathematical equation first, right? Like crossing out common numbers when we do math.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add the C++ tag to your question, so let me write the answer in Python 3 (it should be easy to translate it to C++):

```py
N = int(input("N = "))
D = int(input("D = "))
v = [int(input("v[{}] = ".format(i))) for i in range (0, N)]

count = 0
i, j = 0, 1
while j + 1 < N:
    j += 1
    while v[j] - v[i] > D:
        i += 1
    d = j - i
    if d >= 2:
        count += (d - 1) * d // 2  # // is the integer division

print(count)
```

The idea is to move up the upper index of the triples `j`, while dragging the lower index `i` at the greatest distance `j-i=d` where `v[j]-v[i]<=D`. For each `i`-`j` pair, there are `1+2+3+...+d-1` possible triples keeping `j` fixed, i.e., `(d-1)*d/2`.

Comment: Since N has a max of 10^5 and D has a max of 10^9, it seems that the numbers are *not* simply the integers in order.  Otherwise, D > N is absurd.  OP's given example is weak.

Comment: hmm, right, I overlooked the loading of the vector in the OP's code :-(

Comment: @Prune I completely rewrote my answer

Comment: I see. So instead of calculating combination directly, you used another approach to calculate the amount of combinations. Hmm..